# Pygame - Creature walking through walls

Tags: python, pygame, roguelike

Hello I'm making a roguelike game in pygame, and I am still at the first steps of the game, but I am having a problem. I don't know why, but the creature I created, in this case "skeleton", keeps walking through every single wall. It has a random horizontal movement, but I added the same code I created for my main character, but meanwhile my character can't walk through walls the skeleton just walks through them.

```
import pygame


image = pygame.image.load('model/standing1.png')
Standing = pygame.transform.scale(image, (32, 32))
image = pygame.image.load('map/floor.jpg')
Floor = pygame.transform.scale(image, (32, 32))
image = pygame.image.load('map/rightwall.png')
wallRight = pygame.transform.scale(image, (32, 32))
image = pygame.image.load('enemy/enemyr1.png')
enemyStanding = pygame.transform.scale(image, (32, 32))



walkLeft = []
walkRight = []
walkUp = []
walkDown = []



##### character sprite ######
for i in range(1, 7):
    image = pygame.image.load('model/r' + str(i) + '.png')
    walkRight.append(pygame.transform.scale(image, (32, 32)))

    image = pygame.image.load('model/l' + str(i) + '.png')
    walkLeft.append(pygame.transform.scale(image, (32, 32)))

    image = pygame.image.load('model/u' + str(i) + '.png')
    walkUp.append(pygame.transform.scale(image, (32, 32)))

    image = pygame.image.load('model/d' + str(i) + '.png')
    walkDown.append(pygame.transform.scale(image, (32, 32)))





class struc_Tile():
    def __init__(self, block_path):
        self.block_path = block_path



###### MOBS ###########
class skeleton(object):
    enemyLeft = []
    enemyRight = []

    for i in range (1,7):
        image = pygame.image.load('Skeleton/walk_0' + str(i) + '.png')
        enemyRight.append(pygame.transform.scale(image, (32, 32)))

        image = pygame.image.load('Skeleton/walkl_0' + str(i) + '.png')
        enemyLeft.append(pygame.transform.scale(image, (32, 32)))



    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,endx,endy):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.endx = endx
        self.endy = endy
        self.pathx = [self.x, self.endx]
        self.pathy = [self.y, self.endy]
        self.vel = 3
        self.walkCount = 0

    def draw(self, screen):
        self.move()
        if self.walkCount + 1 >= 12:
            self.walkCount = 0

        if self.vel > 0:
            screen.blit(self.enemyRight[self.walkCount//3], (self.x, self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1
        else:
            screen.blit(self.enemyLeft[self.walkCount//3], (self.x, self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1

    def can_move(self, dx, dy):
        new_x = self.x + dx
        new_y = self.y + dy
        if gamemap[new_x][new_y].block_path == False:
            if gamemap[new_x + cellWidth][new_y].block_path == False:
                if gamemap[new_x][new_y + cellHeight].block_path == False:
                    if gamemap[new_x + cellWidth][new_y + cellHeight].block_path == False:
                        self.x += dx
                        self.y += dy
                        return True

    def move(self):
        if self.vel > 0:
            if self.x < self.pathx[1] + self.vel:
                self.x += self.vel
            else:
                self.vel = self.vel * -1
                self.x += self.vel
                self.walkCount = 0
        else:
            if self.x > self.pathx[0] - self.vel:
                self.x += self.vel
            else:
                self.vel = self.vel * -1
                self.x += self.vel
                self.walkCount = 0


class creature(object):
    def __init__(self, name, hp = 10):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = hp








#### Character ###############
class player(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 5
        self.walkCount = 0

        self.images = {}
        self.images['walkleft'] = walkLeft[:]
        self.images['walkright'] = walkRight[:]
        self.images['walkup'] = walkUp[:]
        self.images['walkdown'] = walkDown[:]



    def draw(self, screen, direction):
        if self.walkCount + 1 >= 18:
            self.walkCount = 0

        if direction == 'standing':
            screen.blit(Standing, (self.x,self.y))
            self.walkCount = 0
        else:
            screen.blit(self.images[direction][self.walkCount//3], (self.x,self.y))
            self.walkCount += 1


    def can_move(self, dx, dy):
        new_x = self.x + dx
        new_y = self.y + dy
        if gamemap[new_x][new_y].block_path == False:
            if gamemap[new_x + cellWidth][new_y].block_path == False:
                if gamemap[new_x][new_y + cellHeight].block_path == False:
                    if gamemap[new_x + cellWidth][new_y + cellHeight].block_path == False:
                        self.x += dx
                        self.y += dy
                        return True

####
def createmap():
    newmap = [[struc_Tile(False) for y in range(0, mapHeight)] for x in range (0,mapWidth)]
    for x in range(0, mapWidth):
        for y in range (0, mapHeight):
            if y < 32 or y + cellWidth >= mapHeight:
                newmap[x][y].block_path = True
            elif x < 32 or x + cellWidth >= mapWidth:
                newmap[x][y].block_path = True


    return newmap

##### Draw map ####

def drawmap(maptodraw):
    for x in range(0, mapWidth, cellWidth):
        for y in range(0, mapHeight, cellHeight):
            if maptodraw[x][y].block_path == True:
                screen.blit(wallRight, (x, y))
            else:
                screen.blit(Floor, (x, y))

###### Colision with walls ########

def block_element(x, y, maptoblock, block=True):
    x_cells = int(mapWidth / cellWidth)
    y_cells = int(mapHeight / cellHeight)

    start_x = int(x * cellWidth)
    start_y = int(y * cellHeight)

    end_x = start_x + cellWidth
    end_y = start_y + cellHeight

    print(start_x, end_x)

    if x >= 0 and x < x_cells:
        if y >= 0 and y < y_cells:
            for x in range(start_x, end_x):
                for y in range(start_y, end_y):
                    maptoblock[x][y].block_path = block

    return maptoblock

pygame.init()

mapHeight = 960
mapWidth = 960

cellWidth = 32
cellHeight = 32

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((mapWidth, mapHeight))

####### add or remove walls ##########

gamemap = createmap()
gamemap = block_element(8, 6,gamemap)    #add walls
gamemap = block_element(5, 10,gamemap)
gamemap = block_element(0, 8, gamemap, block=False)        ### remove walls
gamemap = block_element(0, 9, gamemap, block=False)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
character = player(64, 64, 32, 32)
skeletonmob = skeleton(200,200,32,32,500,500)


run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(18)
    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:

            run = False
    drawmap(gamemap)
    skeletonmob.draw(screen)

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed() #### movement keys
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and character.can_move(0 - character.vel, 0):
        character.draw(screen, 'walkleft') #move left
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and character.can_move(character.vel, 0):
        character.draw(screen, 'walkright') #move right
    elif keys[pygame.K_UP] and character.can_move(0, 0 - character.vel):
        character.draw(screen, 'walkup') #move up
    elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and character.can_move(0, character.vel):
        character.draw(screen, 'walkdown') #move down
    else:
        character.draw(screen, 'standing')
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed to evaluate if the `skeleton` can move. Call `can_move` in `move` and invert the direction is `can_move` returns false:

```py
class skeleton(object):
    # [...]

    def move(self):
        if not self.can_move(self.vel, 0):
            self.vel *= -1

        elif self.vel > 0:
            if self.x < self.pathx[1] + self.vel:
                self.x += self.vel
            else:
                self.vel = self.vel * -1
                self.x += self.vel
                self.walkCount = 0
        else:
            if self.x > self.pathx[0] - self.vel:
                self.x += self.vel
            else:
                self.vel = self.vel * -1
                self.x += self.vel
                self.walkCount = 0
```